# Add view above scrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have following construction: View -> ScrollView -> View.
I want to have one view that will always be above scrollView, always visible and always in same spot. I tried to add UIView to first View (that hold scrollView in it). However, its not work. Please take a look:

[image]

The view i select is not visible. I want it to be visible always in same spot, overlaying scrollView content. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

**In front, not on top**

Assuming you mean *in front*:

The view you added (aptly named `view`) is behind, not in front of the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: where exactly should i put it?

Comment: In the interface editor views that are at the top of the list appear behind views that are at the bottom of the list.